# Put cursor in cell containing today's date when sheet is opened

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

using the today function I have today's date in cell C4.  The range of data to query is G4:af250.

My script is:

```
onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var dates = sheet.getRange(G4:AF250).getValues();

  var today = C4();
    }
Goto 'today'()  }
}`
```

I am getting error after error, instead of going to the cell in the range with today's date.

Help.

Comment: Why goto? which language is that?

Answer (score 1):

You are starting to get a handle on the syntax of JavaScript, so keep at it. Maybe try working your way through the learning path at CodeAcademy, to help hammer it in.

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dateRange = sheet.getRange('G4:AF250');
  var dates = dateRange.getValues();
  var today = sheet.getRange('C4').getValue();

  // Find today in the dateRange
  var found = false;
  var row=dates.length-1;
  while (row >= 0 && !found) {
    var col=dates[row].length-1;
    while (col>=0 && !found) {
      // If the array cell matches 'today', stop looking.
      if (!(today > dates[row][col]) && !(today < dates[row][col])) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
      col--;
    }
    if (!found)
      row--;
  }

  // Use search row & col to offset to a cell relative to dateRange start
  var active = dateRange.offset(row, col,1,1);

  // Move user's cursor to today's date, if it is found in dateRange
  if (found)
    sheet.setActiveRange(active);
}
```

---

**Edit:** Explanation of some key points.

This function searches the range `G4:AF250` for a match to the content of `C4`. It's expected that the content of that cell is `=TODAY()`. If that assumption is correct, then the result should be that the user's cursor will be placed in the matching cell, *if it exists*.  If no match is found, the cursor will be left where it started (A1).

**Date Matching** is tricky in Javascript. You can't just test for equality, so this code tests whether `today` is before or after the date in a target cell; if it's not before or after, then it must be the same. (There are other ways, see [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript).)

There are no tests included here to ensure that the values being read from the spreadsheet are, in fact, Date objects. If you've got strings or numbers in C4 or the dateRange, then matches won't be made. For example, the date `1/4/2014` is not equal to the string `"1/4/2014"`.

To test for matches, our code must loop through two dimensions of the `dateRange`. We could do this with `for` loops, from 0 up. In this case, though, we start at the maximum and work back down. This choice was handy for the definition of the `active` cell, later.

As always, when dealing with Spreadsheets, you need to be aware that Spreadsheet row and column references start from 1, while Javascript arrays start at 0. This means that once we read a range of values using `getValues()`, we have a two-dimensional array that is `0..(maxRows-1)` by `0..(maxCols-1)`. If you eliminate the `-1`, you will end up trying to reference a non-existent value, and generate an error.

Comment: Thank You very much for your help.  You are 110% correct I am struggling with the java syntax.  This code works great but it takes me to 2/8/2014 today.  Do I need to remove the '-1' from the .length?

Comment: Tried a few "self-edits" with no luck.  I am definitely missing some understanding of how the code is working.

Comment: Regardless of the date in the today cell, the routine always leaves the cursor at cell AD250.  It should be stopping at cell V75, where 01/07/2014 is.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: There was a bad cell reference, should be C3, not C4.  Stupid error.  I can share spreadsheet with you if you give me your email?

Comment: Does it matter if the dates are atop columns that contain some rows with text fields, some numeric fields, some merged fields?

Comment: Unfortunately after the change it is not working.  The cursor moves to a new cell, but not the right one.

Comment: Old Code: if (!(today > dates[row][col]) && !(today < dates[row][col])) {

New Code: if (String(dates[row][col]) == String(today)){

Comment: The above change was the key to making the script do what I wanted.  Thanks for your help!  Now if I could figure out how to make the script work when I open the sheet on my iphone, too, I would be 100% set.  Thanks again.